# Не отображается шаблон: Method Not Allowed (GET): /account/logout/

Tags: python, django

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в причине, по которой не отображается кастомный шаблон logout. Отмечу, что если я нажимаю на LOG OUT в админке джанго, то меня редиректит на шаблон, но не по адресу http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/logout/ а по http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/logout/. Делаю все в точности как в книге Django 4 в примерах (страницы 200-205).

Console output:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 08, 2023 - 08:17:52
Django version 5.0, using settings 'bookmarks.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[08/Dec/2023 08:18:05] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1433
Method Not Allowed (GET): /account/logout/
Method Not Allowed: /account/logout/
[08/Dec/2023 08:18:17] "GET /account/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

/account/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from account import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

settings:

```
    LOGIN_URL = 'login'
    LOGOUT_URL = 'login' # Менял 'login' на 'logout' - не помогло. 

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'account',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
```

account/templates/registration/logged_out.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Logged out{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Logged out</h1>
    <p>
        You have been succesfully logged out.
        You can <a href="{% url 'login' %}">log-in again</a>
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <span class="logo"><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Bookmarks</a></span>
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <ul class="menu">
       <li {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
       <a href="{% url "dashboard" %}">My dashboard</a>
       </li>
       <li {% if section == "images" %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
       <a href="#">Images</a>
       </li>
       <li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
       <a href="#">People</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
    <span class="user">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %} Hello {{ request.user.first_name|default:request.user.username }},
        <a href="{% url "logout" %}">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url "login" %}">Log-in</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
<div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

account/views.py:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

структура проекта:

```
.
├── account
│   ├── static
│   │   └── css
│   │       └── base.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── account
│   │   │   └── dashboard.html
│   │   ├── registration
│   │   │   ├── logged_out.html
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   ├── password_change_done.html
│   │   │   ├── password_change_form.html
│   │   │   ├── password_reset_complete.html
│   │   │   ├── password_reset_confirm.html
│   │   │   ├── password_reset_done.html
│   │   │   ├── password_reset_email.html
│   │   │   └── password_reset_form.html
│   │   └── base.html
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── bookmarks
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── README.md
```

[image: HTTP ERROR 405]

Answer (score 0):

**Мне помог такой вариант**. Страница выхода **не отображается**, но разлогинивается.

account/views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect
    
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/') # на главную страницу сайта
```

/account/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns += [
    path('accounts/logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

]
```

> Буквально перехватываешь разлогин и используешь свой метод, а
> остальные методы из встроенной библиотеки используются.

Я вычитал, что к сожалению в Django 5.0 вообще вырежут LogoutView, а в 4.1 уже считается устаревшим способом разлогина через GET запрос.
[Подробнее тут.](https://runebook.dev/ru/docs/django/topics/auth/default#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

В книге испоьзуется Django==4.1.0

А ты скорее всего используешь 5.0, где удалили выход из системы по запросу GET

[Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView)

```
pip3 uninstall Django
pip3 install Django==4.1.0
```

и должно заработать

Для продолжения в 5 версии Джанго (подсмотрел на странице Django administration)
внести в base.css

```
#logout-form {
    display: inline;
}


#logout-form button {
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

и в base.html

```
<!--<a href="{% url "logout" %}">Log-out</a>-->
<form id="logout-form" action="{% url "logout" %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">Log out</button>
</form>]
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

я тоже читал эту книгу LogoutView не поддерживается Django 5
попробуй этот код должен работать

```
   <form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit">Log out</button>
   </form>
```